# How to ignore images in the textAngular editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textangular

Facing issue with the textAngular editor when user copy and paste text.
(clip board contains text and image)

You can find library from here https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular.

Comment: Any feedback or suggestion Shiva?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrjdzb2t/3/). It uses [ta-past directive](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Directives) of textAngular and replaces all image elements by using regex `.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,"");` on your  input string.

#### View

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
        <div text-angular 
             name="testEditor" 
             ng-model="htmlContent" 
             ta-paste="stripFormat($html)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
angular.module('test', ['textAngular'])
  .controller('testController', function($scope, $timeout, textAngularManager, $filter) {

  $scope.htmlContent = '<p>Hello There!</p>';

  $scope.stripFormat = function ($html) {
    return $html.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,"");
  };
});
```

Comment: Hey @lin how do i ignore the a href tag in text-angular editor?

Comment: @Shiva please create a new question and link it here. I will help you there.

Comment: @Shiva sorry, what?

Comment: fixed that issue

Comment: @Shiva fixed what?